# VAS loading distortion in amplifier

Tags: transistors, amplifier, buffer, distortion, total-harmonic-distortion

I'm trying to solve the VAS (voltage amplifier stage) loading distortion in a three-stage amplifier.

Excluding the input stage (called IPS in the circuit below), here is represented a typical VAS stage and the output stage of the amplifier.

Reasearching on lowering distortion in a three-stage amplifier, I've been testing this circuit as example:

[image]

In green the VAS stage, and the red the output stage.

Now, assuming this is the simplest form of three-stage amplifier in existence, with a simple negative feedback correction factor, the distortion increases as the impedance of the load on the output decreases (yes, obviously).

But what I noticed is that the greatest distortion of this amplifier is derived from how much current is required from the second stage (VAS) by the final output stage (OPS).

So the obvious choice would be to use an intermediate stage, or buffer, between the VAS and the OPS to greatly reduce the influence that the load impedance has on the VAS.

[image]

Here, in yellow, I've added the buffer stage.

And here is the problem:

In both the simulator I've tested, LTSpice and PSpice, also tried to change transistors, models, adding beta and Vbe tolerances, this work perfectly in every montecarlo simulation: greatly reduces the influence of the impedance of the load on the amplifier, and the output distortion is reduced by a lot too. Almost as it's without a load.

In the reality, after assembly the amplifier, the distortion measured with the spectrum analyzer did not change at all between the version without the buffer stage and with the buffer stage. So, what happened? I can't figure that out.

Comment: Most likely supply voltage or ground variations coupling into the VAS. Could you show us a full schematic, including all compensation capacitors etc, as well as the board layout?

Comment: @JonathanS. you can assume a "Blameless" amplifier by Douglas Self, with bootstrapped and constant current VAS, all in a perfectly regulated bench power supply. So I can highly exclude power supply problems.

Comment: If it's the "blameless" amp, your problem is likely the power rail. The VAS integrator is referenced to the negative rail. Any variations in that rail couple directly through to the output. If your negative rail has an impedance of 10 Milliohms (!), drawing 1A from the output already introduces 10mV of noise on the negative rail, which translates directly into 10mV distortion that the feedback loop has to compensate for. In reality, it's likely even worse. This is why I requested you to show the layout - you have to physically keep the output currents away from the VAS supply voltage.

Comment: Did you increase the voltage across the bias block by about 1.2 volts when you added the middle stage?

Comment: @Andyaka yes, ditortion in fact is pretty much second order, not odd harmonics.

Comment: @JonathanS. I said that VAS is insulated by a resistor and the bootstrap capacitors, so it's not possible that the current absorbed by the rail influences the stage. I tried everything to exclude the VAS itself: adding CCS, change tipology (single, cascode, EF, CFP...), and nothing worked. Probably because I still have too much current absorbed by the output stage, but I don't know why, because the buffer should have solved this.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't provide a *full* schematic and board layout. Also, I'm not talking about the collector load of the VAS, I'm talking about its emitter connection. It's a common-emitter amp with an integration capacitor after all.